# Laravel 5.5 The email and password field is required

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am new and installed Laravel 5.5 and trying to work on login functionality. I am using custom fields to login; user_name and user_password. When I submit I am getting

- The email field is required.
- The password field is required.

but my fields are user_name and user_password in the user table

Login controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


use AuthenticatesUsers;


protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}

/**
 * Logout, Clear Session, and Return.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function logout()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    Log::info('User Logged Out. ', [$user]);
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();

    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
}

protected function getCredentials(Request $request){
    return $request->only('user_name', 'user_password');
}


}
```

View

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div>
  <a class="hiddenanchor" id="signup"></a>
  <a class="hiddenanchor" id="signin"></a>
  <div class="login_wrapper">
    <div class="animate form login_form">
      <section class="login_content">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <h1>Login Form</h1>
          <div>
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="user_name" value="{{ old('user_name') }}" required autofocus>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="user_password" required>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-default submit">Log in</button>
            <a class="reset_pass" href="#">Lost your password?</a>
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div class="separator"></div>
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the trait `AuthenticatesUsers` and it is responsible for validating the data after the user submitted the form. If you take a look at this file, you will see this method:

```php
/**
 * Validate the user login request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
```

More specifically, as you can see, this method is in charge for calling the validator on the fields name "password" and by the method `username()`. If you only wanted to custom the username field, you could overwrite the `username()` method in `LoginController` class:

```php
public function username()
{
    return 'user_name';
}
```

But since you want to custom both the username field name and the password field name, I suggest that you overwrite the `validateLogin()` method in the `LoginController` class:

```php
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'user_name' => 'required|string',
        'user_password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried validateLogin override only in my LoginController, I'm still getting same errors.

Comment: rather getting `"Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::validateLogin() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\laravelAuth\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 31 ◀"` error

Comment: In login **These credentials do not match our records.** error comes up. I know Laravel uses bycrpt for password; I have converted my password as well. Is anything I'm missing?

Comment: This is a little vague. Can you provide more information? Plus you should probably post a new question regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must go to **app/User.php** and change

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];
```

to

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'user_email', 'user_password',
];
```

It will solve your problem. But i must suggest to you change your view form field to email, password instead of user_name, user_password

Comment: I think you are mixing things up here. The `$fillable` member variable defines the attributes that are mass-assignable ([Mass Assignement](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment)). The field names of the form in the HTML and the table column names are totally independent.